# .NET how to enable net named pipes programatically?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm building an program for a service that uses WCF over net named pipes.

The protocol was off by default in my machine, so I'd like to turn it on programatically.

There doesn't seem to be much information available besides [a powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6906626/385273)  (also [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd206997(v=sql.105).aspx)) and a [registry key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9093521/385273) solution that is also fairly vague.

Can someone provide more clarity on this?  Specifically, how to turn on "Named Pipe Activation", as in the screenshot below, via C# code.  Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Neither of your two links have anything to do with Named Pipe Activation, those are for enabling named pips on SQL Server. Also, the way to turn it on during the install depends on the installer software you are using, please edit your question and include details about what installer software you are using.

Comment: That's probably why I'm confused, there seem to be many keywords used interchangeably. Edited to remove the word "installer", let's just say I have a program that I want to run to do whatever that checkbox does, but programatically.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054282/how-can-you-programmatically-turn-off-or-on-windows-features

Comment: @DavidG looks promising! Thank you, investigating.

Comment: Are you hosting your WCF app in IIS or as a windows service? Turning on Named Pipe Activation is only required for using named pipes while hosting in IIS. Windows services should work fine with named pipes without it.

Comment: Not knowingly using IIS. I'm using `System.ServiceModel` and a duplex contract with `ServiceBehavior`s and `OperationContract`s.  Next step is to get it running as a Windows service.  My code didn't work until I had turned on that feature.  The WCF service endpoint is of the form  `net.pipe://localhost/myEndpoint`.

Comment: @DavidG I've posted my solution thanks to your link.  If you wanted to post a solution I'll accept that one (and probably delete mine).  Cheers! Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Since it's a duplicate, I've closed it as such. Glad you have your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keywords that I was looking for were "turning Windows features on and off", not named pipes specifically.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054282/how-can-you-programmatically-turn-off-or-on-windows-features) describes how to do this (thanks @davidg).

I filtered the available features with

```
dism /online /get-features | find "Pipe"
```

...which let me build the command [outlined here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/575345b4-b6f5-4c42-829e-00dd18f737fe/enable-disable-windows-turn-on-or-off-feature-in-win-10-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral):

```
dism /online /enable-feature:WCF-Pipe-Activation45 /norestart
```